# Deriving variance of VAR(1)

Tags: variance, vector-autoregression

I am reading [Cochrane's](https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/research/papers/time_series_book.pdf) (p.35) book on Time series and I'm a bit rusty on my linear algebra so I was hoping someone could help me derive the variance of a VAR process.

Consider a VAR(1):

$x_{t} = Ax_{t-1} + Cw_{t}$

where $C = [\sigma_{\epsilon} \quad0  \quad \sigma_{\epsilon}]'$ and $E(w_{t}w_{t}') = I$

Then he says

> the forecast error variances are $x_{t+1} - E_{t}(x_{t+1}) = Cw_{t+1} \implies var_{t}(x_{t+1}) = CC'$
>
> $x_{t+2} - E_{t}(x_{t+2}) = Cw_{t+2} +ACw_{t+1} \implies var_{t}(x_{t+2}) = CC' + ACC'A'$

I am able to follow up until the $\implies var_{t}(x_{})$ part. But I don't understand how/why he introduces the transpose of $C,A$.

Comment: Does this help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/194698/covariance-of-two-time-series-driven-by-a-restricted-var1-model/194704#194704

Comment: That looks quite promising, thanks a lot Christoph!